# how can we dynamically generate OR conditions in IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to make a comparison statement like

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]== b[0] or  a[i] == b[1] or a[i] == b[2] or a[i] == b[3]
```

How can I generate the **or** part dynamically, Nested for loops won't work

Why Nested loops won't work?

This loop will generate mathematical constraints for an LP, using nested loops will create many duplicates and contradicting statements.

Comment: use `if any([ai == bi for ai in a for bi in b]):` or `if any([ai in b for ai in a]):` or `if set(a) & set(b):`

Comment: I think the keyword you want is `in`: `a[i] in b`

Comment: Nested for loops do work. Why impose artificial limitations?

Comment: Nesting in my case wont work, i am adding more details to question to explain the same

Answer (score 1):

use `if a[i] in b` if want to compare with all `b[i]'s`